# Uniqueness of Dual basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I have read that the dual basis for the dual space of a vector space is unique. What does it mean in this sense to be unique? That it is the only basis possible or the only basis of this form?

Comment: What you remember reading is not true, since for finite-dimensional spaces, the double dual is isomorphic to the space, so if your space is $\mathbb R^2$, not only does it have infinitely many bases, so does its double-dual. What you may have really read is that there's a "natural" isomorphism from $V$ to the double-dual of $V$, one that can be defined without reference to any basis. That's true when $V$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: So can I interpret that as the dual basis for a given basis for $V$ is unique if $V$ is finite dimensional?

Comment: See @BrL's answer. It's not just that there's a single basis of the dual, rather, there's only one basis for the dual that has a nice relationship to a particular basis of the primal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that if $V$ is finite-dimensional and $(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ is a basis of $V$ then there exists a unique basis $(e_1^*,\ldots,e_n^*)$ of the dual space $V^*$ such that for $1 \leq i,j \leq n$ one has $e_i^*(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$, where $\delta_{ij}$ is the Kronecker symbol.